# Bind TextBox Width from ColumnDefinition Width XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox, width

In my WPF project i want to bind TextBox Width property from ColumnDefinition Width.
Now, it's not working !

I used a converter (GridLengthConverter) to convert data to width.

This is my code :

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SearchWhite}"  Name="tbSearch"
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mic:DataGrid}},
Path=ShowSearchBoxes, Converter={StaticResource visibleConverter}}" Width="{Binding
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ColumnDefinition}},
Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource gridLengthConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

gridLengthConverter is GridLengthConverter from assembly : PresentationFramework.

I get an error "Unable to convert data attribut 'Converter'..." (translation from french).

Someone can helps ?

Comment: I suspect it's because `ColumnDefinition` is not a direct parent of `TextBox`. You probably need to bind to the `Grid`, then set the `Path` of the binding to something like `ColumnDefinitions[0].Width`

Answer (score 4):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=Width}" 
                 Grid.Column="0" Height="20"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Small correction: {Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}"

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding your text box to width of column 1, all you need to do is leave out the Width property definition and set `HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"`

For example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column = "1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="120" Name="textBox1" />
</Grid>
```

The textbox now should be of height 120 and width 100.